# regex find or return the second one

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like this

```
`state`.`stateID`
```

and I want to write a regex to select the second part, stateID and I'm not good in regex, can anyone help me to solve this please?
**it's just an example I actually want the second part of every given strings**

Comment: simply `stateID` will select the first instance of "stateID". Is this what you mean? you might need to expand on your question a bit.

Comment: How about just: stateID ? That works fine in EditPad when using RegEx..

Comment: I want the second part of the string it just an example.
@philtune

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: @user3885927 I think it doesn't matter, for answer to your question PHP

Comment: You can use ('[^']+') and get the second matching group. I changed the quotes so that SE doesn't format it

Comment: Or https://regex101.com/r/jN0xD8/1 ... too many ways to proceed for this simple case xD

Answer (score 1):

As an example, if you have:

```
`Alabama`.`AL`
`Alaska .`AK`
`Arizona`.`AZ`
`Arkansas`.`AR`
`California`.`CA`
```

Use this regex to capture the second text:

```
/.+`(\w+)/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
$re = "/`([^`]+)`/"; 
$str = "`state`.`stateID`"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print $matches[0][1];
```

**Output:**

```
`stateID`
```

**Explanation:**

`[^`]+` - matches one or more non quote characters.

`()` - groups the match string

Comment: is there any way to return just stateID not `stateID`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $re = "/`([^`]+)`/"; 
> $str = "`state`.`stateID`"; 
>
> preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
>
> print $matches[0][1];
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> `stateID`
> ```
>
> is there any way to return just stateID not `stateID`

Of course - just use `$matches[1][1]`, not `$matches[0][1]`.